# How to disable button in angular securely?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I just found out that you can go to the html and just remove the disable="true" from the button and enable it back again

So my question is if there is a way to securely disable buttons so that no one can enable them back again using the html.

Comment: You can do, `[disable]=“disabled”` and in your component, check if the button is disabled when clicked.

Comment: Depends on what the button does and what are you doing. The client side code ( frontend ) is downloaded and executed by the client's browser, therefore it has full control over the executed code. The browser applies many security protocols and policies to limit the scope of the client permissions, however you have to introduce security on the backend side. From the frontend you are constantly communicating with the backend and the backend will provide all the information about the user, permissions, etc.. If the button navigates to x route, then you implement guards to avoid unallowed access

Comment: Thank you everyone for sharing your knowledge
Btw whats up with the downvotes I am not sure what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "safely" disable stuff on the client side. User can modify not only HTML, but the javascript as well, so even if there would be "secure" ways to disable buttons, users could still check what javascript will run and run it.

Answer (score -2):

If its a button , you may apply [disabled]="disable" and prevent them from running the function bound to it.

```
<button [disabled]="checkIfDisabled" (click)="handleClick()">Click me</button>
public handleClick() {
   if(!checkIfDisabled) {
     ... do stuffs
   }
}
```

With this you can prevent someone from running the function even they took out the disabled property on the button element